# what is the sharp step, terrace in stm image?

Tags: solid-state-physics

hi i`m interested in stm so i have read some paper about stm.
but lack of my background, i have trouble with understanding.
paper says that sharp steps, flat terraces and few serface imperfection indicate the good quality of the sample
where is the sharp step and flat terraces in this picture? and what is their definition?
also, how can i know that the sample has few imperfection by seeing this picture?

the paper is `review of scientific instrument, Development of 4pp in a stm for insitu electrical transport measurement, 2015
[image]

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

They are referring to the terrace-ledge-kink (TLK) model of crystal growth ([Google images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=terrace+ledge+kink+model&espv=2&biw=1871&bih=995&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRzYz6qIzOAhWHHsAKHaUfCyEQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=JDR_tl4ve2B_zM%3A) may help you).

The terraces are the flat surfaces of the crystal. When a new layer of atoms is partially formed, there is a step (usually, but not always, a single atom in height) that separates the existing terrace from the new terrace that's forming on top, and you must 'step up' to get onto this new layer. That's the 'step' (or 'ledge').

[image]

You can see that this crystal lacks imperfections from the second image (c). Each of those individual bumps is a single atom, and you can see that they form a perfect lattice (i.e. no defects). Defective surfaces usually have dark spots - like this:

[image]